# trace inequalities: linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, trace

If S is any $n \times n$ real, symmetric, invertible matrix and D is any $n \times n$  diagonal matrix such that $0\prec D \prec I$ then does there exist a constant $\gamma$ such that:

$trace(S^{-1}DS^2DS^{-1})\leq \gamma \cdot n$

Comment: Huh? Take $\gamma=trace(S^{-1}DS^2DS^{-1})/n$. Or do you want the inequality to hold over all possible such $S,D$?

Comment: I want $\gamma$ to be independent of n.

Comment: So then take $\gamma=trace(S^{-1}DS^2DS^{-1})$. Really my point is that if you are fixing $S$ and $D$ in the first place, then the trace is determined. So of course there exists a $\gamma$: just take any real number large enough so that $\gamma n$ is larger than the trace.

Comment: Oh sorry..my bad..i am not fixing S and D...i want it over all possible S and D...i would like their sizes $n$ to be very large. And so, i was introspecting if there exists any dimension independent constant $\gamma$.

Comment: But $D \prec I$ so the above counter example do not work.

Comment: Ok sorry missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking whether there exists a constant $\gamma$, that is independent of $n,S$ and $D$, such that $\operatorname{trace}(S^{-1}DS^2DS^{-1})\le\gamma\,n$, the answer is no. Let $x>0$ and
$$
D=\frac14\pmatrix{1\\ &2},\ U=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&-1},\ S=U\pmatrix{1\\ &x}U^T.
$$
Then $S^{-1}DS=\frac14U\pmatrix{\frac32&-\frac x2\\ -\frac1{2x}&\frac32}U^T$ and hence
$$
\operatorname{trace}(S^{-1}DS^2DS^{-1})
=\left\|\frac14\left(\frac32,\,-\frac1{2x},\,-\frac x2,\,\frac32\right)\right\|^2,
$$
which is unbounded as $x\to0$ or $x\to\infty$.

Comment: This is great! Many thanks.